# Refreshing query of AsyncTaskLoader with OnQueryTextListener

Tags: android, asynctaskloader

I have a custom AsyncTaskLoader that performs a search based on some query text entered into an ActionBar search:

```
class SearchLoader extends AsyncTaskLoader<List<String>> {

    private static final String TAG = SearchLoader.class.getName();

    private List<String> data;
    private String query;
    private DataStore dataStore;

    public SearchLoader(Context context, DataStore dataStore, String query) {
        super(context);
        this.dataStore = dataStore;
        this.query = query;
    }

    @Override
    public List<String> loadInBackground() {
        try {
            return dataStore.find(query);
        } catch (SearchException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, String.format("Error performing search, query: %s", query), e);
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

I have hooked up an OnQueryTextListener to refresh the loader's data by performing a new search when the query changes:

```
@Override
public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
    query = !TextUtils.isEmpty(newText) ? newText : null;
    getLoaderManager().restartLoader(SEARCHRESULTS_LOADER, null, this);
    return false;
}
```

I am aware that I need to call getLoaderManager().restartLoader.

However, what I am not sure about is how to set the new query text on the loader itself?

1. I don't have access to the loader instance to call a setter
2. The arguments of the restartLoader as far as I know are only used if a new loader needs to be created

What is the recommended way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, `restartLoader()` causes `onCreateLoader()` to be called. I don't know why this works, as it seems contrary to what the documentation says about re-using existing loaders. Your code already is passing the saved query instance variable to the loader constructor, so it should do what you want.

[This Android sample](https://code.google.com/p/android-source-browsing/source/browse/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/LoaderRetained.java?repo=platform--development&name=android-cts-4.1_r1) from Google shows `restartLoader()` being called when the query text changes.

Comment: The private LoaderManagerImpl class has slightly different Javadoc notes for these two methods, that actually better describe what's happening. In particular, for restartLoader(), it says "Call to re-create the Loader associated with a particular ID. If there is currently a Loader associated with this ID, it will be canceled/stopped/destroyed as appropriate. A new Loader with the given arguments will be created and its data delivered to you once available."